# Executing ssh command in c program using popen()

Tags: c, shell, ssh, popen, ssh-keys

When I try executing this using popen it returns this error but when I run this in terminal it works!

```
 popen("ssh -n -f *.*.*.* 'sshfs -o nonempty *.*.*.*:/home/foo/bar/ /foo1/foo2/foo3'", "r");
```

error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I use public and private key to ssh without passwords and they work properly as this command run flawlessly in terminal.

I changed it to this :

```
popen("ssh -n -f *.*.*.* `sshfs -o nonempty *.*.*.*:/home/foo/bar/ /foo1/foo2/foo3`", "r");
```

It return errors too.

error :

```
fuse: bad mount point `/foo1/foo2/foo3': No such file or directory
Cannot fork into background without a command to execute.
```

I also tried escipping the internal `""` this way : `\"    \"` but it hangs!

Comment: What happens if you leave out the single quotes, except around the `*.*.*.*:/home/foo/bar/` part?

Comment: Just to clarify: your second variant of the `popen` call performs a command substitution of `sshfs ...` locally - passing its output to the `ssh` command and it doesn't find the mount dir - while the first variant of `popen` is passing the command  for execution on the other server. The `-f` option to `ssh` implies `-n` BTW. Try adding `-vv` to the `ssh` command to debug some more.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ssh with `/usr/bin/ssh`,  do the same with other commands, like sshfs. Specify the full path of the command, `/usr/sbin/foo`  or whatever the case may be.  popen does not necessarily use the same shell you have at the command line to execute commands.  Check your documentation.

Comment: I found out it was working though that error `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` so I just redirect stderr to a file.